# Date not passing from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I currently have a datepicker in my view which holds the date when a user picks one. I need to thereafter pass the date to the Controller, however it is empty when reaching the controller. i am unsure if I am approaching this in the wrong way. Below is my code of what i've just explained.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.location_id = new SelectList(db.Locations, "location_id", "location_name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DatePickerModel PMV)
    {
        TempData["dti"] = PMV.dtmDateIn.ToString("dd/mm/yy");
        TempData["dto"] = PMV.dtmDateOut.ToString("dd/mm/yy");

        return RedirectToAction("reservation_step_1", "Home");
    }
```

So I am basically trying to return the values from the Index View which is as follows:

```
@model FleetHire.Models.DatePickerModel    
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {
       @Html.DropDownList("locationId", ViewBag.location_id as SelectList, "Select Location", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dtmDateOut, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @style = "height: 30px" } })

          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dtmDateIn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @style = "height: 30px" } })

           <input type="submit" style="background-color:#DDDDDD; width: 139.5px; height: 30px;" value="SEARCH" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("reservation_step_1", "Home") + "'");"/>

<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function ()
        {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "+0:+1",
                minDate: "+0",
                showOn: "both",
                buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar' style='height: 25px; margin-top: 6px;margin-bottom: -4px; border-style: none;'></i>"
            });
        });
    </script>
}
</div>
   }
```

After receiving these values I am thereafter transferring the values to the "reservation_step_1()" action in the controller to work out the difference in the dates. As follows:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult reservation_step_1()
    {
        DateTime O = DateTime.ParseExact(TempData["dto"].ToString().Trim(), "dd/mm/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime I = DateTime.ParseExact(TempData["dti"].ToString().Trim(), "dd/mm/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var days = I.Subtract(O).Days.ToString();

        ViewBag.totdays = days;
        return View(db.Step_1.ToList());
    }
```

Once the view loads for the "reservation_step_1()" action, the ViewBag.totdays value is 0.

Can anyone please help me fix this? I don't know what or where I am going wrong

Errors when running:

[Values of O and I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6BJ6.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiSew.png)

Comment: If you can't get datePicker's `Value` in controller change your js to `$("#dtmDateOut").datepicker({...});`

Comment: Are `PMV.dtmDateIn` and `PMV.dtmDateOut` contains value from submitting the form? If both of them contain values in method with `[HttpPost]`, the `TempData` may become possible issue.

Comment: are you getting O and I value ? If yes then let me know the values.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yes both TempData["dti"] and TempData["dto"] contains values from PMV.dtmDate out and PMV.dtmDateIn from form submission

Comment: @MohanPrajapati Unfortunately I am not, please see screenshots in question that I have just added

Comment: Well, `TempData` seems messed up there. Try `TempData.Peek("dto").ToString().Trim()` and see if `O` contains value. If not, try using `TempData.Keep()` before redirection.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have tried your changes and nothing seem to work, I have tried hard coding 2 date values to TempData["dti"] and TempData["dto"] in the [HttpPost] method and it passes those values over to the [HttpGet] method and returns the difference between the dates. I assume the problem lays with getting the values from the View to the [HttpPost] method in the controler

Comment: Sounds like the `datepicker` values are not converted to `DateTime` during POST request because they have incorrect format or conflicted with current culture. In this case, using `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and/or `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` attribute in model property may work.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I've tried that and nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ASP.NET MVC `TempData` could be used to share data between controller actions. For me, I would prefer to pass strongly typed objects as follows:

```
public ActionResult reservation_step_1(string dto,string dti)
{
   //...
}

public ActionResult Index(DatePickerModel PMV)
{
    string dti = PMV.dtmDateIn.ToString("dd/mm/yy");
    string dto = PMV.dtmDateOut.ToString("dd/mm/yy");
    return RedirectToAction("reservation_step_1", "Home", new { dto = dto,dti = dti});
}
```

Comment: values are not getting stored in dti and dto, they are not accepting and storing these values in the variables